# Eigenfunction as equivalence class

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be an arbitrary index set, $k$ a continuous kernel with values in a field $\mathbb{F}$, and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure. Consider the Fredholm integral operator
$$Tu = \int_C k(s,t)u(t)d\lambda \hspace{0.8cm} u\in L^2(\mathcal{X}), \hspace{0.1cm} \mathcal{C} \text{ compact in } \mathcal{X}$$
The operator $T$ is a map into the space of continuous functions $C(\mathcal{X})$. Let $\sigma$ be an eigenvalue of $T$. What is an associated eigenvector: a function or an equivalence class?  If it's reasonable to view it as either, what would be a suitably general way to define the notion of an eigenfunction?

P.S. Clearly, the equivalence class associated with $\sigma$ will *contain* the eigenfunction associated with $\sigma$. The question is whether there is a reasonable expectation that the term 'eigenfunction' should subsume both types of mathematical object given the singularity of the word is by its very nature unifying. One proposal would be to deem *all* eigenfunctions equivalence classes, in order to cater for spaces such as $L^2$.

Comment: Since you are talking about $L^2$ it would have to be equivalence classes. It would only make sense to talk about functions if that eigenvector had a continuous representative

Comment: If one is a class and another is a function, and 'eigenfunction' is singular, which of them is the eigenfunction?

Comment: Eigenfunction in this context is just "slang". The justification for using this term at that point is that it is simply easy to not differentiate between the terms "function" and "equivalence class". It just matters how you deal with the eigenvectors: You can integrate them, but you can't evaluate them at one point - again, except if there is a continuous representative. So yes, $L^2$-equivalence classes are often called functions, but using them, everybody knows that you can not evaluate them.

Comment: Thank you for giving this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The above turns out not to be a well-defined integral operator. In order to define such an operator one may map the output of $T$ back to $L^2(\mathcal{X})$.

Let the *inclusion operator* $$I: \mathcal{C}(\mathcal{X})\mapsto L^2(\mathcal{X})$$

map the image of $T$ to the equivalence class it belongs to in $L^2(\mathcal{X})$. We can then define the integral operator $$S:L^2(\mathcal{X})\mapsto L^2(\mathcal{X}): Su=I\circ Tu$$

The notion of an eigenvector of $S$ is now well-defined.